# Glassfish + mod_proxy_ajp downloads getting truncated

Tags: java, apache, proxy, glassfish, ajp

I've just upgraded to Glassfish 3.1.2 and I'm having problems with file downloads getting truncated:

Glassfish has a jk-listener configured and I'm running it behind Apache with mod_proxy_ajp.

```
ProxyPass / ajp://www.mydomain.com:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://www.mydomain.com:8009/
```

My app generates a zip file on-the-fly and this file is now getting truncated to 256Kb when I download via the ajp proxy. However if I bypass Apache and use the Glassfish http port directly the download completes fully (around 700Kb).

I'm seeing these errors in the Apache logs:

```
ajp_check_msg_header() got bad signature 2c69
ajp_ilink_receive() received bad header
ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
(120007)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: dialog to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009 (www.mydomain.com) failed
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Did you try mod_jk instead of mod_proxy_ajp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our setup with Apache and mod_jk, after upgrading from GlassFish 3.0.1 to 3.1.2, I had to disable chunking in the HTTP tab of the JK network listener.

See this: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18446